# How does one get IAM permissions after AWS Cognito sign in using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS Cognito as my authentication mechanism for an iOS app that I'm writing in Swift. I'm having a difficult time retrieving the user's access token once the user has successfully signed in. I will include some code below. I ask questions on here as a last resort. The documentation has just been to confusing and inconsistent for me to follow. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Note: The core problem is that after sign in, no AWS resources can be accessed

AppDelegate

```
// setup service configuration

let serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: CognitoIdentityUserPoolRegion, credentialsProvider: nil)

// create pool configuration
let poolConfiguration = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(clientId: CognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientId, clientSecret: CognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientSecret,
poolId: CognitoIdentityUserPoolId)

// initialize user pool client
AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.register(with: serviceConfiguration, userPoolConfiguration: poolConfiguration, forKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProviderKey)

// fetch the user pool client we initialized in above step
let pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProviderKey)
```

SignInViewController

```
 AWSMobileClient.default().signIn(username: username, password: password) { (signInResult, error) in

    if let error = error  {

         print("\(error.localizedDescription)")

    }
    else if let signInResult = signInResult {

       switch (signInResult.signInState) {

       case .signedIn:

           print("User is signed in.")

       default:

           print("Sign In needs info which is not yet supported.")
       }

   }
}
```

Resources that I've already looked at:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/blob/master/CognitoYourUserPools-Sample/Swift/CognitoYourUserPoolsSample/SignInViewController.swift

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/authentication

I'm stumped

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking the question Ryan, if you have anymore questions, it may be easier to get some traction on it and have the documentation improved by asking it over in the Github Repo (https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues) as it is more active over there.

AWSMobileClient works with the `awsconfiguration.json` file.

You can run through the automated set up to see what is placed inside `awsconfiguration.json`: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/authentication#automated-setup

If the automated set up does not fit your needs, you can also manually craft the `awsconfiguration.json` file to be used by AWSMobileClient.

1. Use Amplify CLI to provision and generate the `awsconfiguration.json` file.

```
{
        "IdentityManager": {
            "Default": {}
        },
        "CredentialsProvider": {
            "CognitoIdentity": {
                "Default": {
                    "PoolId": "XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab",
                    "Region": "XX-XXXX-X"
                }
            }
        },
        "CognitoUserPool": {
            "Default": {
                "PoolId": "XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234",
                "AppClientId": "XXXXXXXX",
                "AppClientSecret": "XXXXXXXXX",
                "Region": "XX-XXXX-X"
            }
        }
    }
```

2. Place it in your project, added to Bundles for AWSMobileClient to access
3. In code, initialize AWSMobileClient

```
AWSMobileClient.default().initialize { (userState, error) in
            if let userState = userState {
                print("UserState: \(userState.rawValue)")
            } else if let error = error {
                print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
```